# Testing Arg.Any Task

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nsubstitute, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to test the orders of which the methodes are called. The issue I have is that I can't seem to find a good way to mock a Task object.

I am using `NSubstitute` and `Entity Framwork 6`. This is sort of what my code looks like.

```
Received.InOrder(() =>
{
    IDbSet<TEntity>.SingleOrDefaultAsync(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>);
});
```

To further emphasize what I need an answer to, it is what I should insert to Arg.Any<>.

Comment: If you down vote, please leave a comment. Is it inconclusive, do you not understand the question, etc.

Comment: It might help to break the problem down into smaller chunks, such as first mocking a simple int-valued Task object, and then separately building up to the EF call.

Comment: Does David Tchepak's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658873/3419534 help?