# Unit Test NService.Send from an API Controller

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus, nsubstitute

I have an API Controller which publishes a command using NServiceBus.  I am using NUnit and NSubstitute for testing.  I want to test that certain properties from the model are populated on the command

Here is my controller with a route.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/fileService")]
public class FileServiceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("releasefile")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ReleaseFile(FileReleaseAPIModels.ReleaseFileModel model)
    {
        var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;


        if (model.FileType.Equals("ProductFile"))
        {
            _logger.Info($"Releasing Product files for date: {model.FileDate.ToShortDateString()} ");
            _bus.Send<IReleaseProductFiles>("FileManager.Service", t =>
            {
                t.FileId = Guid.NewGuid();
                t.RequestedDataDate = model.FileDate;
                t.RequestingUser = currentUser?.Name;
                t.RequestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            });
        }
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

In my test, I substitute(mock) Ibus and try to validate the call received.  Here is the test method:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task TestReleaseProductsFile()
    {
        var bus = Substitute.For<IBus>();
        var dbContent = _container.Resolve<IFileManagerDbContext>();
        var apiContext = new FileServiceController(bus, dbContent);

        //Create a snapshot
        var releaseDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var result = await apiContext.ReleaseFile(new ReleaseFileModel
        {
            FileDate = releaseDate,
            FileType = "ProductFile"
        });

        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null, "Result is null");

        Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<OkResult>(), "Status code is not ok");

        bus.Received(1)
            .Send<IReleaseProductFiles>(Arg.Is<string>("FileManager.Service"), Arg.Is<Action<IReleaseProductFiles>>(
                action =>
                {
                    action.FileId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    action.RequestedDataDate = releaseDate;
                    action.RequestingUser = String.Empty;
                    action.RequestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                }));
    }
```

This results in error - even though the message is actually sent.  Here is the error message:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
    Send<IReleaseProductFiles>("Capelogic.Service", Action<IReleaseProductFiles>)
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
    Send<IReleaseProductFiles>("Capelogic.Service", *Action<IReleaseProductFiles>*)
```

I am obviously missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the `Action<IReleaseProductFiles>` argument to `Send` -- we can't automatically tell if two different actions are the same. Instead, NSubstitute relies on the references being equivalent. Because both the test and the production code create their own `Action` instance, these will always be different and NSubstitute will say the calls don't match.

There are a [few different options for testing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658873/906). These examples relate to `Expression<Func<>>`, but the same ideas apply to `Action<>`s.

In this case I'd be tempted to test this indirectly:

```
[Test]
public async Task TestReleaseProductsFile()
{
    var bus = Substitute.For<IBus>();
    var returnedProductFiles = Substitute.For<IReleaseProductFiles>();

    // Whenever bus.Send is called with "FileManager.Service" arg, invoke
    // the given callback with the `returnedProductFiles` object.
    // We can then make sure the action updates that object as expected.
    bus.Send<IReleaseProductFiles>(
            "FileManager.Service",
            Arg.Invoke<IReleaseProductFiles>(returnedProductFiles));

    // ... remainder of test ...

    Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<OkResult>(), "Status code is not ok");
    Assert.That(returnedProductFiles.FileId, Is.Not.EqualTo(Guid.Empty));
    Assert.That(returnedProductFiles.RequestedDataDate, Is.EqualTo(releaseDate));
    Assert.That(returnedProductFiles.RequestingUser, Is.EqualTo(String.Empty));
}
```

I'd recommend having a look through the previously mentioned answer though to see if there is a better fit for your situation.

Comment: Perfect.  I just had to make one modification - Instead of:
Arg.Invoke<Action<IReleaseProductFiles>>(returnedProductFiles));

Changed TO:
Arg.Invoke<IReleaseProductFiles>(returnedProductFiles));