# How to test if a function received a specific delegate using NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, nunit, nsubstitute

I would like to test if function received a specific delegate as parameter. Is it possible in NUnit with NSubstitute?

My interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Sort(Func<IEnumerable<int>, IOrderedEnumerable<int>> f);
}
```

My test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void Sort_WhenCalled_CallsWithPassedArgument()
    {
        // Arrange
        IMyInterface mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();

        // Act
        mock.Sort(x => x.OrderBy(y => y));

        // Assert
        mock.Received().Sort(x => x.OrderBy(y => y));
    }
}
```

I also tried with argument matchers, but it always fails.

Comment: For reference [NSubstitute - Testing for a specific linq expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654053/nsubstitute-testing-for-a-specific-linq-expression)

Comment: Thank you. It's not what I expected, but now I know that it's not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is that your argument type is `Func<>`, not `Expression<Func<>>`. With Expression you could inspect the tree to check method names etc.

However, you can unit test against the concrete example for `OrderBy` (e.g. as opposed to `OrderByDescending()`, because given a collection of ints `6,4` `OrderBy()` will always re-sort it to be `4,6`. So the following works:

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class Class1
  {
    [Test]
    public void Sort_WhenCalled_CallsWithPassedArgument()
    {
      // Arrange
      IMyInterface mock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface>();

      Func<IEnumerable<int>, IOrderedEnumerable<int>> func = null;
      mock.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.Sort(Arg.Any<Func<IEnumerable<int>, IOrderedEnumerable<int>>>())).Do(
        x =>
          {
            func = x.Arg<Func<IEnumerable<int>, IOrderedEnumerable<int>>>();
          });

      // Act
      mock.Sort(x => x.OrderBy(y => y));

      // Assert
      var result = func(new[] { 6, 4 });

      Assert.That(result.FirstOrDefault(), Is.Not.EqualTo(6));
      Assert.That(result.FirstOrDefault(), Is.EqualTo(4));
    }
  }
```

Of course, the logic is somewhat fragile, so you need to decide if you really want to test that an exact method is used in a func (and then maybe refactor the code to allow to check for this specific method by other means or switch to `Expression`) or just the behaviour is enough for you.