# Mocked method returns null when using anonymous types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I have this code:

```
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyTests
{
    public interface ICompanyBL
    {
        T GetCompany<T>(Expression<Func<Company, T>> selector);
    }

    public partial class Company
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var companyBL = Substitute.For<ICompanyBL>();

            //Doesn't work
            companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID }).Returns(new
            {
                RegionID = 4,
            });

            //Results in null:
            var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID });

            //This works:
            //companyBL.GetCompany(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Company, Company>>>()).Returns(new Company
            //{
            //    RegionID = 4,
            //});

            //Results in non null:
            //var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new Company { RegionID = c.RegionID });
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code, the `company` var is null.
However, the commented out code works fine and results in a non null value.

Why does it not work with the anonymous type?
Is there some way to get this to work with anonymous types?

NSubstitute version = 1.10.0.0.

.NET Framework version = 4.5.2.

Comment: you do not have any condition like "Arg...."  So , Substitute doen't know what you want to return.

Comment: It knows what I want to return because I have .Returns(new
            {
                RegionID = 4,
            });

Comment: What is the actual implementation of `T GetCompany<T>(Expression<Func<Company, T>> selector);` why you want to mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the previous options may not be desirable, another approach may be available to you, if you have access to the (in this case) source for `CompanyBL`.

This alternative is to mark the methods needed to be mocked as `virtual` and have the mock inherit from the concrete class `CompanyBL` rather than implement the whole interface.

The reason you may want to do this is to make the mock less fragile .. ie when someone extends the `ICompanyBL` interface they will not need to add implementations to the mock.

While this is not an answer for specifically how to use NSubstitute I feel it is a worthwhile alternative. A variation may be to change CompanyBL to have protected virtual methods for functionality that needs to be replaced in the mock. Writing code that is more testable should be a concern which arguably merits these types of changes.

Answer (score 3):

Because by default configured value will be returned only when arguments passed to the method are equal to the arguments configured with the mock.

`Expression<Func<Company, T>>` is a reference type and will be equal to another instance when both instances reference same object.

In your case configured mock and actual code receive different instances of two different objects.

You can use working approach suggested by David and Dave.
Which solving compilation error when NuSubstitute can not figure out which type is used for a selector.

Such approaches will work, but for failing tests provides little information about actual reason (in case wrong selector is given to the method)

Sometimes implement your own mock will have some benefits

```
public class FakeBusiness : ICompanyBL
{
    private MyCompany _company;

    public FakeBusiness For(MyCompany company)
    {
        _company = company;
        return this;
    }

    public T GetCompany<T>(Expression<Func<MyCompany, T>> selector)
    {
        return selector.Compile().Invoke(_company);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
[Fact]
public void TestObjectSelector()
{
    var company = new MyCompany { RegionId = 1, Name = "One" };
    var fakeBl = new FakeBusiness().For(company); // Configure mock

    var actual = fakeBl.GetCompany(c => new { c.Name }); // Wrong selector

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new { RegionId = 1 }); //Fail
}
```

And failed message now is more descriptive:
*Expectation has member RegionId that the other object does not have.*

Passing test

```
[Fact]
public void TestObjectSelector()
{
    var company = new MyCompany {RegionId = 1, Name = "One"};
    var fakeBl = new FakeBusiness().For(company); // Configure mock

    var actual = fakeBl.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionId });

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new { RegionId = 1 }); // Ok
}
```

Comment: It says "the type arguments for method GetCompany() cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Try `companyBL.GetCompany(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Company, T>>>()).Returns(call => ...);`.

Comment: @DavidTchepak it says "The type or namespace T could not be found"

Comment: Sorry `T` should probably be `int` (or whatever type your expression returns).

Comment: @DavidTchepak it returns an anonymous type.

Comment: Makes it trickier. :) Try the original expression but keep `ReturnsForAnyArgs`. (Sorry I'm commuting atm so can't test, but figured I should try to respond while we're both online)

Comment: @DavidTchepak I don't think T is going to work because it's not the name of a type.

Comment: @DavidTchepak now I'm having an issue where the value is null but called from a different project:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945013/mocked-method-returning-null-when-called-from-a-different-project

Comment: I support creating the mock manually over trying to force this case of generics into a framework that was not built for this particular situation.

Comment: @Fabio I think your answer is most correct. My answer provides an NSubstitute-specific work-around, while yours most effectively solves the problem. If you are happy to, we can combine the answers into yours and I can delete mine. ("Intro" and "Handed-coded substitute" from your answer, then can copy/paste my "Incomplete work-around" section if you think that is useful.)

Comment: @David, I afraid NSubstitute approach will not work when class under the test is in different assembly(which is the most of the cases for tests and "production" code), see OP's another question, check link from three comments above.

Answer (score 2):

[@Fabio's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58927239/906) is correct:

> `Expression<Func<Company, T>>` is a reference type and will be equal to another instance when both instances reference same object.
>
> In your case configured mock and actual code receive different instances of two different objects.

You can read more about this in related questions such as [NSubstitute - Testing for a specific linq expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654053/nsubstitute-testing-for-a-specific-linq-expression).

**Solving using a hand-coded substitute**

Please see [@Fabio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58927239/906) for a good explanation of how to hand-code a substitute to solve the problem and provide useful assertion messages. For complex substitutions sometimes it is simplest and most reliable to skip a library and to generate the exact type you need for your test.

**Incomplete work-around with NSubstitute**

This case in particular is more difficult than the standard expression-testing case (using `Arg.Any` or `Arg.Is`) because we can't explicitly refer to the anonymous type. We could use `ReturnsForAnyArgs`, but we need to be clear about which generic method version we're calling (again, we can't explicitly refer to the anonymous type required for `T`).

One hacky way to work around this is to pass the expression as you were originally doing (which gives us the correct generic type), and use `ReturnsForAnyArgs` so the exact identity of that expression does not matter.

```
[Fact]
public void Test() {
    var companyBL = Substitute.For<ICompanyBL>();

    // Keep expression in `GetCompany` so it calls the correct generic overload.
    // Use `ReturnsForAnyArgs` so the identity of that expression does not matter.
    companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID }).ReturnsForAnyArgs(new {
        RegionID = 4,
    });

    var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID });

    Assert.NotNull(company);
}
```

As noted in @Nkosi's comment, this has the drawback that it only does a minimal assertion on the type used for the selector expression. This would also pass in the test above:

```
var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { RegionID = 123 });
```

As an aside, we do get some very basic checking of the expression, as the combination of generic type and anonymous types means that selecting the wrong field will not compile. For example, if `Company` has `string Name` property we will get a compile error:

```
companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID }).ReturnsForAnyArgs(new { RegionID = 4 });

var company= companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.Name });
Assert.Equal(4, company.RegionID); // <- compile error CS1061

/* 
Error CS1061: '<anonymous type: string Name>' does not contain a definition 
for 'RegionID' and no accessible extension method 'RegionID' accepting a first 
argument of type '<anonymous type: string Name>' could be found (are you missing
a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)    
*/
```

Comment: For the record, I disagree with this answer (the workaround specifically) as it is a false positive.

Comment: @Nkosi I agree with your disagreement. I will update the answer :)

Comment: Backwards_Dave, please unmark this as accepted. I believe @Fabio's edited answer is most correct.

Comment: @Nkosi I would appreciate your feedback on this revised answer. We do get some correctness checking with this approach. Both this and @Fabio's approach will fail given a selector like `var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { RegionID = 123 });` I'm happy to make this a community wiki if we want to collaborate on an answer.

Comment: In my opinion the OP is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) targeting the mocking framework itself. Until they clarify what it is they are **actually** trying to achieve we are basically trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 1):

As Fabio and David Tchepak have already pointed out, my code wasn't working because it couldn't find a match for my method's argument because it was a different object to what was set up in the mock.

Here's another way to fix this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var companyBL = Substitute.For<ICompanyBL>();
        Expression<Func<Company, object>> x = c => new { c.RegionID };
        companyBL.GetCompany(x).Returns(new
        {
            RegionID = 4,
        });

        var company = companyBL.GetCompany(x);
    }
```