# Mocked method returning null when called from a different project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I have this test class:

```
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace MyTests
{    
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var companyBL = Substitute.For<ICompanyBL>();

            companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID }).ReturnsForAnyArgs(new
            {
                RegionID = 4,
            });

            var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new { c.RegionID });

            var dataRetriever = new DataRetriever(companyBL);
        }
    }
}
```

and this code in another project:

```
namespace MyTests
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public interface ICompanyBL
    {
        T GetCompany<T>(Expression<Func<Company, T>> selector);
    }

    public partial class Company
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRetriever
    {
        public DataRetriever(ICompanyBL companyBL)
        {
            //This is null:
            var company = companyBL.GetCompany(c => new
            {
                c.RegionID
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `company` var is `null`.
However, when the code is all contained in the same .cs file in the same project, the value is not `null`.

Why is the value `null` when used in another file in another project?

NSubstitute version = 1.10.0.0.

.NET Framework version = 4.5.2.

Issue submitted in Github:
https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/598

Comment: Custom mock for `ICompanyBL` should solve this issue, because it is not based on the type of passing arguments as NSubstitute does

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how nsubstitute works but I believe you are running into issues where anonymous types only match inside single assembly, they are always different across assemblies.

Roughly you are mocking `companyBL.GetCompany<TestAssembly.AnonymousTypeForRegionID>` and your tested code calls `companyBL.GetCompany<ProductAssembly.AnonymousTypeForRegionID>`.

The easiest fix - use some type to pass data shared between those two assemblies. Even `Tuple` would do. More ideas in [Return/consume dynamic anonymous type across assembly boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993200/return-consume-dynamic-anonymous-type-across-assembly-boundaries)