# How to mock an Expression<Func<object,bool>>> using like It.Is<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I'm trying to mock the following:

```
     [Fact]
    public void GetTipoBaixa()
    {
        var tipoBaixa = new TipoBaixa() { CodTipoBaixa = 1, DscTipoBaixa = "Sem Financeiro", IdTipoBaixa = 1 };
        string filtro = "Sem";

        Expression<Func<TipoBaixa, bool>> expression = ((TipoBaixa t) => t.DscTipoBaixa.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(filtro.ToUpper()));

             //_tipoBaixaRepository.Setup(s => s.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TipoBaixa, bool>>>(), null, null)).Returns(new List<TipoBaixa>()
        //{  tipoBaixa}.AsEnumerable());

        _tipoBaixaRepository.Setup(s => s.Get(It.Is<Expression<Func<TipoBaixa, bool>>>(expression), null, null)).Returns(new List<TipoBaixa>()
        {  tipoBaixa}.AsEnumerable());


        var tipoBaixaResult = _tipoBaixaService.Get(filtro).Content;

        var result = tipoBaixaResult.FirstOrDefault()?.IdTipoBaixa;

        Assert.Equal(tipoBaixa.IdTipoBaixa, result);
    }
```

This is my service Get:

```
   public IEnumerable<TipoBaixa> Get(string filtro)
    {
        Expression<Func<TipoBaixa, bool>> expression = ((TipoBaixa t) => t.DscTipoBaixa.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(filtro.ToUpper()));
        var response = this._repository.Get(expression, null, null);
        return response;
    }
```

this is my repository:

```
  public IEnumerable<TEntidade> Get(Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntidade>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntidade>> orderBy = null, Expression<Func<TEntidade, object>>[] includes = null)
    {
        var query = this._dbSet.AsQueryable();

        if (predicate != null)
            query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        if (includes != null)
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Dominio.Entidades.TipoBaixa, bool>>
>    to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Dominio.Entidades.TipoBaixa, bool>>, bool>>`

Using the `It.IsAny` it works, but that's not what I need, because what I need is when someone changes the filter in my service, I want that my test fail.

When i just pass the "expression" in Mock, the mock doesn't work, because it seems not to be the "same expression".

Comment: You're missing the `bool` in `It.Is<Expression<Func<TipoBaixa, bool>>>`

Comment: Actually, i have already tried with this too, same error, i just posted wrong :-(, anyway, thanks

Comment: Well, the error says what's wrong (even if you did abbreviate it). You're passing an expression of a `Func` of an expression and `bool`, rather than an expression of a `Func` of `TipoBaixa` and `bool`. You can try passing `expression.Compile()` to `It.Is`...

Comment: The same error trying with expression.Compile()

Comment: Don't mock it, use database in-memory to test actual implementation. If you can not use database in-memory, use collection of items inside mock and execute actual expression against this collection to check that proper expression is given. Mocking framework designed to reduce amount of boiler plate code, but when framework is an obstacle - create yuor own mock object.

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927012/mocked-method-returns-null-when-using-anonymous-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927012/mocked-method-returns-null-when-using-anonymous-types)