# How to test expressions equality

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient way to test equality of lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283537/most-efficient-way-to-test-equality-of-lambda-expressions)
>   [How to check if two Expression<Func<T, bool>> are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673205/how-to-check-if-two-expressionfunct-bool-are-the-same)

How to test that two expressions are the same like this sample

```
        string firstname = "Ahmed";
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp1 = (s) => s.Contains(firstname);
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp2 = (s) => s.Contains(firstname);

        Console.WriteLine(exp1 == exp2);//print false as two references are no equal
```

now how to ensure that expression1 equals to expression2 , as they have the same criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for `ExpressionEqualityComparer` which can show how to do it.

https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Expressions/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if the expressions are equal, not just that they always evaluate the same way, you can do this:

```
exp1.ToString() == exp2.ToString()
```

Note that even insignificant changes will cause this to return false, like making it `j => j.Contains(firstname)` or using `exp2` from this class:

```
public class Test
{
    static string firstname;
    public static Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp2 = s => s.Contains(firstname);
}
```

(even though the lambdas look the same in the code, the `ToString`s show that one is using `Test.firstname` and the other is using a compiler-generated class's `firstname`)

Still, this might be useful depending on where your expressions come from.