# How to test for a Match with FakeItEasy on a predicate call?

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate, fakeiteasy

I have the following call in my code:

```
var dbResults = new List<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF>();
dbResults = dateTimeFilter == null
    ? new List<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF>(
        CrossReferenceRelationshipRepository.GetAll()
                .ToList().OrderBy(crr => crr.ToPartner))
    : new List<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF>(
        CrossReferenceRelationshipRepository.SearchFor(
            crr => crr.HistoricEntries
                .Any(he => he.ModifiedDatetime > dateTimeFilter))
                .ToList().OrderBy(crr => crr.ToPartner));
```

and I am trying to use FakeItEasy to verify that when the `dateTimeFilter` has a value, the `SearchFor(…)` is being called within my repository with the correct Function.

So my test looks something like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => crossReferenceRelationshipRepositoryMock.SearchFor(A<Expression<Func<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF,bool>>>.That
    .Matches(exp => Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime>>(((BinaryExpression)exp.Body).Right).Compile().Invoke() == filterByDate)))
    .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

Which is not correct. 
What would be a way to test the whether or not I am calling `SearchFor(…)` with the correct expression?

```
crr => crr.HistoricEntries.Any(he => he.ModifiedDatetime > dateTimeFilter)
```

The actual value being passed into `SearchFor(…)` is `DateTime.MinValue` so I changed my assertion to:

```
A.CallTo(() => crossReferenceRelationshipRepositoryMock.SearchFor(A<Expression<Func<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF, bool>>>.That
    .Matches(exp => Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime>>(((BinaryExpression)exp.Body).Right).Compile().Invoke() == DateTime.MinValue)))
    .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

which is failing and the exception I am getting is

```
System.InvalidCastException:
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN'
  to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression'.
```

and I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I should have answered this earlier. It is true that Blair Conrad and I had a chat and he helped me understand how to test the predicates better. Based on his recommendation I came up with the following solution.

In my tests I created a helper Expression extractor show below:

```
private static string ExpressionExtractor(Expression<Func<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF, bool>> predicate)
{
    var expression = ((BinaryExpression) ((LambdaExpression) ((MethodCallExpression) predicate.Body).Arguments[1]).Body);
    var value = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(expression.Right, typeof (object))).Compile().Invoke();

    return value.ToString();
}
```

And then in my tests I could do my assert like this:

```
//Assert        
A.CallTo(() => crossReferenceRelationshipRepositoryMock.SearchFor(A<Expression<Func<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF, bool>>>.That
    .Matches(exp => ExpressionExtractor(exp) == "20/01/2014 14:06:55")))
    .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Twice);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Disclosure** - VasilisP and I chatted a little about this yesterday.

In a way, this isn't really a FakeItEasy problem. Your approach for setting up an argument matcher within an `A.CallTo` call is sound. The problem is that the lambda you supplied to match the predicate is not working. This brings the question down to the "how can I tell if an expression is what I want it to be?".

There are other StackOverflow questions that ask questions similar to this, such as

- [Most efficient way to test equality of lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283537/most-efficient-way-to-test-equality-of-lambda-expressions),
- [How to check if two Expression<Func<T, bool>> are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673205/how-to-check-if-two-expressionfunct-bool-are-the-same), and
- [How to test expressions equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229338/how-to-test-expressions-equality)

One of those approaches may work for you.

However, the immediate cause of the exception you see is that the passed-in predicate isn't a `BinaryExpression`, it's a `MethodCallExpression`. You could consider altering your test to account for that and follow the path where it leads you.

I filled in some class definitions and extracted the matcher to this function and was able to at least locate the dateArgument in the predicate:

```
public bool IsPredicateGood(Expression<Func<CrossReferenceRelationshipEF, bool>> predicate)
{
    var typedPredicate = (MethodCallExpression) predicate.Body;
    var innerPredicate = ((LambdaExpression)typedPredicate.Arguments[1]).Body;
    var dateArgument = ((BinaryExpression) innerPredicate).Right;
    return dateArgument != null; // not a real test yet, but you could adapt
}
```

In general, though, I'd warn against testing quite like this - it seems a little fragile to me. Of course, you may have a good reason for this approach. But if it suits you, another way to go may be to just capture the predicate and then interrogate it by having it run against a known list of candidate objects. If it filters the way you want, then it passes.
That way if someone changes the passed-in predicate in a way that would still work, perhaps by switching the operator to a `<` with the date on the left, the test would still work. I just throw that out as another option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have posted my working solution below. Sorry it took me ages.