# How to wait for a call that takes a specific linq expression as an argument

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, expression, fakeiteasy

I Have a call I wish to check has happened. This call is to a method that takes a Linq expression as an argument. This expression tests an objects id against the id of a local variable where the expression is declared. How can I make a fake it easy call to that triggers only when the Linq expressions are equal (with the local variable substituted in) or if that is not possible trigger when the local variable used in the linq expression is equal to a certain value.

My current code looks like this

```
   A.CallTo(() => SomeMethod.FindBy(item=> item.ItemId == 3)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

As the call to and this in the code being tested.

```
SomeMethod.FindBy(item=> item.ItemId == id)
```

where id is a local variable. This does not work as id is not substituted in when the call is made and i get an error like this.

```
SomeInterface`1[[someItem, someItemFolder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].FindBy(item=> (item.ItemId == 3))
  Expected to find it exactly once but found it #0 times among the calls:
    1: SomeInterface`1[UKHO.WeeklyRecipes.EFModels.EFModels.EfTag].FindBy(predicate: tag => (tag.TagId == value(UKHO.WeeklyRecipes.BusinessLayer.PreferenceQueries+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).id))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because FakeItEasy cannot tell whether the two expressions are the same. When you supply an object as an argument constraint, FakeItEasy tries to [match the argument value exactly](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#matching-values-exactly). In this case, it means calling the `Expression`'s `Equals` method. To quote the documentation:

> When checking for argument equality, FakeItEasy uses `object.Equals`. If the type to be checked does not provide an adequate `Equals` method, you may have to use the That.Matches method described in [Custom matching](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#custom-matching). Be particularly careful of types whose `Equals` methods perform reference equality rather than value equality. In that case, the objects have to be the same object in order to match, and this sometimes produces unexpected results. When in doubt, verify the type's  `Equals` behavior manually.

So, essentially this means that if you created two variables, one containing the expression `item => item.ItemId == 3` and the other `item.ItemId == id` and compared them using `Equals`, you'd see a `false` result, and so does FakeItEasy.

One approach would be to capture the expression and then interrogate it to see if it acts as you like (that is, but accepting 3 and rejecting non-3s). It's awkward, but comparing predicates is hard. I talk more about this in an answer for [How to test for a Match with FakeItEasy on a predicate call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21444621/1199).