# Moq method with list parameter

Tags: testing, tdd, moq

Hi I have following the following test

```
    <TestInitialize()>
Public Sub Initialise()
    dbHelper = New Mock(Of IDbHelper)
    dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("AreaId"),
                                          New DataColumn("Area"),
                                          New DataColumn("CountryId"),
                                          New DataColumn("Country"),
                                          New DataColumn("SubRegionId"),
                                          New DataColumn("SubRegion"),
                                          New DataColumn("RegionId"),
                                          New DataColumn("Region"),
                                          New DataColumn("Notes"),
                                          New DataColumn("Enabled"),
                                          New DataColumn("FlagIgnoreFactsheet")
                                          })
    dt.Rows.Add(New String() {"0", "", "0", "", "0", "", "0", "", "", "True", "False"})

    Dim paramList As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@AreaId", It.IsAny(Of Int64)))
    paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@AreaName", String.Empty))
    paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@CountryId", 0))
    paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@Enabled", 1))
    paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@ShowAll", 0))

    dbHelper.Setup(Function(db) db.ExecuteReader(It.IsAny(Of String), paramList)).Returns(dt)

End Sub

 <TestMethod()>
Public Sub GetAreaWithParamTest()

    Dim areaRepository As AreaRepository = New AreaRepository(dbHelper.Object)

    Dim result = areaRepository.GetArea(1)

    Assert.IsNotNull(result)
End Sub
```

But the test fails because the dbHelper.ExecuteReader returns a null object instead of the expected Datatable.

It works however if instead of sending params I use It.IsAny(Of List(Of SqlParameter))

Here is the code for GetArea Method

```
Public Function GetArea(ByVal pAreaId As Long) As AreaEntity Implements IAreaRepository.GetArea
        MyResponse = Nothing
        If pAreaId = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Try
            Dim paramList As New List(Of SqlParameter)
            paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@AreaId", pAreaId))
            paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@AreaName", String.Empty))
            paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@CountryId", 0))
            paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@Enabled", 1))
            paramList.Add(New SqlParameter("@ShowAll", 0))

            Dim dt As DataTable = _dbHelper.ExecuteReader("sp_Core_AreaList", paramList)
            MyResponse = _dbHelper.MyResponse

            If IsNothing(dt) OrElse dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing

            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).First()

            Dim result As AreaEntity = New AreaEntity() With {
                .AreaId = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("AreaId")), 0, dr("AreaId")),
                .AreaName = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("Area")), String.Empty, dr("Area")),
                .CountryId = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("CountryId")), 0, dr("CountryId")),
                .CountryName = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("Country")), String.Empty, dr("Country")),
                .SubRegionId = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("SubRegionId")), 0, dr("SubRegionId")),
                .SubRegionName = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("SubRegion")), String.Empty, dr("SubRegion")),
                .RegionId = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("RegionId")), 0, dr("RegionId")),
                .RegionName = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("Region")), String.Empty, dr("Region")),
                .Notes = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("Notes")), String.Empty, dr("Notes")),
                .Enabled = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("Enabled")), False, dr("Enabled")),
                .FlagIgnoreFactsheet = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("FlagIgnoreFactsheet")), False, dr("FlagIgnoreFactsheet"))
            }

            Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            MyResponse = New Response("AreaRepository.GetArea", "Error while loading area information", ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
```

Please Help !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up `ExecuteReader()` method using `dbHelper.Setup(Function(db) db.ExecuteReader(It.IsAny(Of String), paramList)).Returns(dt)` it expects that `paramList` will be passed as a parameter. But actually you pass another one object, however, with the same structure.

**MOQ compares `List`s by reference.** You can face the same issue with `Expression`s also. I've already answered question [Why this mock with Expression is not matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226500/why-this-mock-with-expressionfunct-bool-is-not-matching/19233232#19233232).

I suggest you set up `ExecuteReader()` method using `It.IsAny(Of List(Of SqlParameter))` and then **use** [**Callbacks**](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) **to verify list of parameters**.

There is in axample of using [Callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) from GitHub:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback<int, string>((i, s) => 
        {
            /* your asserts can be placed here */
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a complete beginner in Moq, would you suggest any tutorial/book which can pace me up?

Comment: I think that [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) is enough for the first time. It covers many use cases.