# Expression.Lambda.Compile() cannot comparing parameter string values

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

Basically I am compiling expression at run-time and then I am invoking them with the `DynamicInvoke` methods there are all supposed to return Boolean value, but the problem is that when there is string comparison, it fails. Suppose an expression like that `{x.SomeProp == "value"}` value of SomeProp is `"value"` but when I Execute the `DynamicInvoke` on that expression pass the appropriate object to it and cast the return value to `bool` I get `false` as an answer.

This is the code I use to build expression

```
public static Expression BuildExpression(string propName, Operator op, object value, ParameterExpression paramExp)
{
    var expressionType = new ExpressionType();
    var leftOperand = CreateExpression(paramExp, propName);

    var rightOperand = leftOperand.Type.BaseType == typeof(Enum) ? 
        Expression.Constant(Enum.Parse(leftOperand.Type, value.ToString(), true)) : Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, leftOperand.Type));

    var fieldInfo = expressionType.GetType().GetFields(Enum.GetName(typeof(Operator), op));
    var expressionTypeValue = (ExpressionType)fieldInfo.GetValue(op);

    var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, leftOperand, rightOperand);

    returnExpression;
}

private static Expression CreateExpression(ParameterExpression type, string propName)
{
    Expression body = type;
    body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, propName);

    return body;
}
```

`paramExp` basically is this

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(someObjectType, "x");
```

now this code is does great job building expressions, then I do

```
Expression.Lambda(exp, param).Compile();
```

on it, and then

```
copiledExp.DynamicInvoke(someObj);
```

it works okay when comparing `int`, `double`, `float`, `decimal` and even `enum` values but recently I have come up to a problem comparing strings. It return false on any expression

this is the view of the expression that is getting built. I mean, this is return by the `ToString()` method

```
"(x.SomeStringProp == \"stringValue\")"
```

Comment: Did you try it by explicit casting? Eg: x.SomeProp == new String("value")

Comment: can you provide sample output of `Expression.Lambda(exp, param).ToString()`?

Comment: Maybe these links can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283537/most-efficient-way-to-test-equality-of-lambda-expressions and (ExpressionComparison.cs) https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Expressions/

Answer (score 0):

The equality comparison you have there is between the types `string` and `object` because `Expression.Constant` returns you an expression of type object because `ChangeType` did as well. This means that you get a reference comparison as if you had written `someString == (object)"..."`.

You'll have to build an expression calling `string.Equals` or any other equivalent method. Or, you make the constant have type `string` so that the overloaded equality operator of `string` is selected.

---

`DynamicInvoke` is slower than a direct call because it uses reflection on every call. If you are going for performance with this, compile to a `Func<object>` and have a cast inside the compiled method to convert the `object` parameter to the right type.

Comment: String implements its own equality operator == which calls String.Equals. Its not a reference compare.

Comment: @user957902 expression tree equals does not use overloaded operators. This is not C#.

Comment: The documentation for Expression.Equal says that it will use the overloaded equality operator under the correct circumstances. If you pass two string constant expressions into Expression.Equal you will get an implementing method of {Boolean op_Equality(System.String, System.String)}

Comment: I did not know that. Then, his problem is that `Expression.Constant` returns him an expression of type object. Editing.