# How to get unique id of lambda function for "do once" pattern?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function, uniqueidentifier

I want to implement "do once" pattern that allows me to avoid writing 3 things:

- declaring var first = true
- if(first) Do(...) statement inside repeated block of code
- first = false assignment inside repeated block of code

I also want to avoid workarounds like these:

- manually maintaining and passing unique identification into Do function
- defining once context variable multiple times

So my code should look as simple as this:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once and only once"));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
       foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5}){
               once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop should write once and only once"));
               Console.Write("It should write 6 times");
       }
   }
```

or this:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once and only once"));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once, but only after first instance (out of 3) of previous write."));
       foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5}){
           once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop should write once and only once"));
           Console.Write("It should write 6 times");
           once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once, but only after first instance (out of 6) of previous write."));
       }
       Console.Write("Repeated ending should appear 3 times");
   }
```

If I use ObjectIDGenerator, it does not solve my problem because it gives different Id for Action act for every call in this implementation implementation:

```
public class Once : IDisposable{
    HashSet<long> passed;
    static ObjectIDGenerator idgen = new ObjectIDGenerator();

    public Once(){
        passed = passed.New();
    }

    public bool Do(Action act){
        if(act != null){
            bool firstTime;
            var id = idgen.GetId(act,out firstTime);
            if(!passed.Contains(id)){
                act();
                passed.Add(id);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        passed.Clear();
    }
}
```

How to get unique id of passed lambda function ?
I think it can be done by traversing it as Expression Tree and calculating hash or otherwise serializing it into something that can be placed into HashSet.

But I would prefer if it was possible to find file name and line number in source code that defines that lambda function and use it as id. That would easily solve problem of different places of definition having different unique ids even if definition was copy&pasted.

I guess one way would be to use ObjectIDGenerator for Expression Tree object that represents this lambda function.
Would ObjectIDGenerator return same id for that Expression Tree ?

Another example: how to implement Once class and include nested loop variable it2 into once.Do invokation so that it would be called only twice - once for it2 = 4 and once for it2 = 5:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once and only once"));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
       foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5}){
               once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop should write twice and only twice: {0}", it2));
               Console.Write("It should write 6 times");
       }
   }
```

Another example: how to implement Once class and include outer loop variable it into once.Do invokation so that it would be called only 3 times - once for it = 1, once for it = 2 and once for it=3:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once and only once"));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
       foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5}){
               once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop should write 3 times and only 3 times: {0}", it));
               Console.Write("It should write 6 times");
       }
   }
```

Another clarification:
If there is second lambda function that is defined somewhere else in my code, I want it to have different id even if it's a copy&paste of first lambda and has identical implementation.

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write twice because it's defined in different lines of code"));
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write twice because it's defined in different lines of code"));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
   }
```

Now thinking about it, in an ideal solution I would exclude from id anything that is passed as one of explicit parameters like this `(x,y,z,...)=>...` and include values of any captured context variables referenced by that lambda function. So

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do((arg)=>Console.Write("It should write once {0}",arg));
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write 3 times {0}",it));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
   }
```

Or may be inversion is better:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It should write once {0}",it));
       once.Do((arg)=>Console.Write("It should write 3 times {0}",arg));
       Console.Write("It should write 3 times");
   }
```

Either way the goal of last 2 examples is to show how be able to control cleanly what is included into determination of uniqueness and what is not.

Addressing solution from Jon here is another clarification:

I want to keep definition of once and non-once actions in the same sequence as if they were all non-once, so that order of appearance of a,b,c in my source code does not have to be changed if I decide to write b only once or not:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       Console.Write("a");
       Console.Write("b");
       Console.Write("c");
   }
```

does not have to be changed:

```
using(var once = new Once())
   foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3}){
       Console.Write("a");
       once.Do(()=>Console.Write("b"));
       Console.Write("c");
   }
```

Realistic example - imagine some table with many possible amount fields, imagine that I cannot generate script and execute it in one batch (which is the case with Azure and probably other cloud databases), also imagine that we also define AfterFirst method in our class Once:

```
using(var tblOnce = new Once())
    foreach(var tbl in db.Tables)
       using(var fldOnce = new Once())
          foreach(var fld in tbl.Fields){
            fldOnce.Do(        ()=>conn.Exec(" CREATE TABLE {0}({1} {2})",tbl.Name, fld.Name, fld.SqlType));
            if(fld.Name.EndsWith("Amount"))
                fldOnce.Do(    ()=>conn.Exec(" ALTER TABLE {0} ADD Total money", tbl.Name));
            fldOnce.AfterFirst(()=>conn.Exec(" ALTER TABLE {0} ADD {1} {2}", tbl.Name, fld.Name, fld.SqlType));
            if(fld.PrimaryKey)
                fldOnce.Do(    ()=>conn.Exec(" ALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT PK_{0}_{1} PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED({1})", tbl.Name, fld.Name));
            fldOnce.Do(()=>
                tblOnce.Do(    ()=>conn.Exec(" CREATE TABLE Tables (name varchar(50))"));
                conn.Exec("                    INSERT tables (name) select " + tbl.Name);
            );
          }
```

Comment: Just call `Take(1)` on the sequence to not act on any items after the first.

Comment: If uniquely identifying each action is problematic you could just pass in a context string (e.g. "context1", "context2", etc...) to your Do function.  A simple hashset could track the contexts that have already executed once.  Perhaps not an ideal solution, but trying to hash the expression tree of your action to identify it just feels heavy-handed to me.

Comment: Given nature of my question with availability of simple solution with boolean flags, I am not looking for "not an ideal solution".

Comment: Any solution that involves code duplication is not ideal, which is why multiplying contexts is not ideal. Take(1) is also not ideal because then I have to put all actions, loops and statements into one sequence and start coding in expression trees instead of regular sequence of C# statements and code blocks.

Comment: @alpav You don't need to use expressions at all.  You can just add `Take(1)` to the end of the `IEnumerable` objects you're iterating over and then that's it.

Comment: @alpav okay now you're just changing the requirements every time you do an update. apparently you haven't thought through all the cases properly to discover what functionality you actually want.

Comment: @DLeh: it's not matter of me knowing what I want it's matter of me well explaining what I want in specific cases. What I want is very simple - DRY coding. This is the goal of my question and this is the solution that I am looking for. Me refining examples does not change that goal, so it is not changing requirements. Your answers were helpful to clarify my requirements (not changing them).

Comment: @Servy: Could you put code example with Take(1), I am not sure I follow your approach.

Comment: You don't know how to just paste `Take(1)` onto the end of the sequences you're iterating?  Just call `Take(1)` on every object that actually has a `Take` method in your examples.

Comment: @Servy: I know, but putting Take(1) inside every for loop does not solve problem of having many statements in loop body where some of them are to be executed once and some of them are to be executed for each iteration of loop. Take(1) will execute all statements only once.

Comment: That's not a part of your question; all of your examples involve only acting once in each loop.

Comment: To those who voted to close my question, could you step up and explain how am I supposed to ask question "How to get unique id of lambda function ?" If I don't give examples you will ask for examples, if I give examples, you will offer solutions for those specific examples rather than question title. If I clarify question with more examples I am accused of changing requirements, if I don't clarify I am accused of not being clear. WTF ? Are you just looking for a reason to close any question that you can't answer ?

Comment: People are answering with better ways to solve your problem because there isn't a way to "serialize" a lambda into an identifier. It's one of those cases where you want to use a hammer but others think you might need a screwdriver instead.

Comment: @DLeh: Then I expect to have this simple answer: "It's impossible" and I will mark it as accepted answer and look for screwdrivers myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283537/most-efficient-way-to-test-equality-of-lambda-expressions

Comment: @DLeh: considering that lambda can be passed to Once.Do method as Expression Tree and I can iterate through that tree gaining access to every element of it's body, I think your statement "there isn't a way to "serialize" a lambda into an identifier" is not true. So instead of closing that question let other people (including myself) find and post answer  because I will be looking until somebody else posts good answer. If you still believe this question should be closed could you explain why ?

Comment: @DLeh & others: do you acknowledge that I found simple, specific and useful answer to my question ? Could you please upvote my answer and remove your closing vote even if question does not seem clear to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered elegant and simple solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Once : IDisposable
{
    HashSet<Tuple<string,int>> passed;

    public Once(){
        passed = passed.New();
    }

    public bool Do(Expression<Action> act,
        [CallerFilePath] string file = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0
    ){
        if(act != null){
            var id = Tuple.Create(file,line);
            if(!passed.Contains(id)){
                act.Compile().Invoke();
                passed.Add(id);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        passed.Clear();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the needed id of lambda function is **Tuple(file,line)**.

Of course, we could optimize memory usage by not storing file path or storing it once, but the main problem of getting unique id of lambda function is solved assuming that it's defined only where it's invoked and invoked only where it's defined. That assumption is valid given examples of usage of "do once" pattern.

`Expression<Action>` is not necessary for this solution (we could pass just Action), but it can be used to scan for parameters and captured context variables inside that expression and include their values into determination of lambda function id.

Potential enhancements of identification of lambda functions through scanning of expression tree can be derived from answers to this question [Most efficient way to test equality of lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283537/most-efficient-way-to-test-equality-of-lambda-expressions) which was discovered by [DLeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526704/dleh)

Comment: If anyone wonders what is passed.New(), here is definition:         [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static T New<T>(this T @this, params object[] args)
        {
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
        }

Answer (score 2):

```
using(var once = new Once())
  foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3})
  {
    once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It will write once and only once"))
    foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5})
      once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop will write 3 times and only 3 times: {0}", it))
  }
```

Here I would define this as an operation in terms of the enumerable itself. Consider:

```
public static void OnceAndAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> once, Action<T> all)
{
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    if(en.MoveNext())
    {
      var current = en.Current;
      once(current);
      all(current);
      while(en.MoveNext())
        all(en.Current);
    }
}
public static void Once<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> once)
{
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
    if(en.MoveNext())
      once(en.Current);
}
//Overrides for where the value is not actually used:
public static void OnceAndAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action once, Action<T> all)
{
  source.OnceAndAll(_ => once(), all);
}
public static void OnceAndAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> once, Action all)
{
  source.OnceAndAll(once, _ => all());
}
public static void OnceAndAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action once, Action all)
{
  source.OnceAndAll(once, _ => all());
}
public static void Once<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action once)
{
  source.Once(_ => once());
}
```

Now I can do:

```
new[]{ 1, 2, 3 }.OnceAndAll(
  () => Console.Write("It will write once and only once"),
  it => new[]{4,5}.Once(() => Console.Write("Inner loop will write 3 times and only 3 times: {0}", it))
  );
```

Here the first `Action` passed to `OnceAndAll` is executed only once, but the second is executed every time for that first sequence. It in turn sets up an `Action` to be used in the second 2-item sequence only once per sequence.

Variants of its uses can also handle a lot of your other cases, but not your first:

```
using(var once = new Once())
  foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3})
  {
     once.Do(()=>Console.Write("It will write once and only once"));
       foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5})
         once.Do(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop will write once and only once"));
  }
```

For this I would have something that creates a new action:

```
public static Action Once(this Action toDoOnce)
{
  return () => {
    if(toDoOnce != null)
      toDoOnce();
    toDoOnce = null;
  };
}
public static Action<T> Once<T>(this Action<T> toDoOnce)
{
  return obj => {
    if(toDoOnce != null)
      toDoOnce(obj);
    toDoOnce = null;
  };
}
public static Action<T1, T2> Once<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> toDoOnce)
{
  return (arg1, arg2) => {
    if(toDoOnce != null)
      toDoOnce(arg1, arg2);
    toDoOnce = null;
  };
}
/* and so on … */
public static Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16> Once<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>(this Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16> toDoOnce)
{
  return (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16) => {
    if(toDoOnce != null)
      toDoOnce(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, arg16);
    toDoOnce = null;
  };
}
```

And then use it as so:

```
Action outer = () => Console.Write("It will write once and only once");
var outerOnce = outer.Once();
var innerOnce = ((Action)(()=>Console.Write("Inner loop will write once and only once"))).Once();
foreach(var it in new[]{1,2,3})
{
  outerOnce();
    foreach(var it2 in new[]{4,5})
      innerOnce();
}
```

It means defining the "onceness" outside of the loop, but then that's what the "onceness" is scoped to, to the scope that contains the loop. (For once ever in an application lifetime we already have simple `static`-based approaches).

Comment: I want to keep once and non-once actions in the same sequence as if they were all non-once, so that order of Write(a);Write(b);Write(c) do not have to be broken to wb = Write(b); Write(a); wb(); Write(c) in case if I want to convert Write(b) into once action.

Comment: The second approach I give could be used for that.